# Java program creates files, but files are not visible

Tags: java

I have a program which replaces text in a file based on command line input. Currently it creates a temporary file, and writes the string with the replaced text in the new temporary file. This program works on a desktop in a computer lab on my campus, but when I try to run it on my personal laptop, the temporary file is created, I can find it by printing its canonical path, and file.exists() returns true, but it does not show up on my desktop. 
A search using Windows Explorer yields nothing.

I am running Windows 7 and using TextPad. Does anyone know what might be causing this? I can supply any other necessary information.

**Edit: I am running Windows 7 on a Mac Pro 2011, if that makes any difference at all.**

**Edit: I discovered the problem. I had downloaded Comodo Antivirus software and whenever I created a file it would create it in a VTRoot folder for sandbox purposes. I was able to alter the settings and solved my issue.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReplaceText{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Incorrect format. Use java ClassName textToReplace filename");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    File source = new File(args[1]);
    if(!source.exists()){
        System.out.println("Source file " + args[1] + " does not exist.");
        System.exit(2);
    }


    File temp = new File("temp.txt");
    try(
        Scanner input = new Scanner(source);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(temp);

        ){
            while(input.hasNext()){
                String s1 = input.nextLine();
                String s2 = s1.replace(args[0], "a");
                output.println(s2);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not creating the file? Are you looking in the right place? Have your program print out the file's **full path**, to see exactly where to look.

Comment: e.g., calling `System.out.println(temp.getCanonicalPath());` after creating the temp object.

Comment: Also,.... where is your try's catch block? How do you get notified of file I/O exceptions? This is key.

Comment: The getCanonicalPath() for the temp file returns the Desktop, which is where I have my ReplaceText java file. Also, I edited out the catch blocks just to simply my question, sorry I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Comment: Does this mean that the file is created but it is just not appearing?

Comment: If it has been created, it should "appear". Perhaps you need to refresh your file browser.

Comment: Your catch blocks are not empty, are they?

Comment: No, the catch blocks are not empty, I have them catching IOExceptions and printing the message.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the last comment, I restarted my computer and the temp file was on my desktop. I deleted it and tried to run the program again, but once again it would not show that the file was created.

Comment: look at your desktop using file explorer, and refresh the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. I had downloaded Comodo Antivirus software and whenever I created a file it would create it in a VTRoot folder for sandbox purposes. I was able to alter the settings and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you could not see the temp.txt file it is because it is located in your project directory where your java source code are located.However if you will found it then also it will contain nothing.The reason being you have not closed the output stream to file just place

> output.close()

after the while loop.

Comment: the output stream is closed properly with `try-with-resources` statement. Please look into this for try with resources http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

Comment: That's why i like SO here you could learn new Things.Thanks @RajasubaSubramanian for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try to create file by providing entire file path while creating like

> File(URI uri)

This creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an abstract pathname.

Comment: Can you please edit the code with 1. file creation with full uri and 2. closing output stream after write?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have installed comodo antivirus** then you should follow the instruction :

1.Open the comodo,

2.Click on the settings,

3.Then click on the Containment -> click on the Auto-containment,

4.Then at the top, uncheck the enable auto-containment.